# Passing args[] to R with spaces

Tags: php, r, exec

I have php exec function and i get error when args contains whitespaces  :

```
$cluster = "bla  bla";
$region  = "east  region";


 exec("\"F:\\PROB\\R\\R-3.3.0\\bin\\Rscript.exe\" 
       F:\\web\\Component\\script.R $cluster $region");
```

in my R script:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE) 
cluster <- args[1]
region <- args[2]
...
```

i try use quote `"$cluster"` and `'$cluster'` inside it, but still got error (R script won't run).

What can I change in the exec function to see the string being passed in via args[] as the argument?

Comment: put \" around it and its work :)    `\"$cluster\"`

Answer (score 0):

put \" around it , like this \"$cluster\"